# encrypt and decrypt connection string in XML file

Tags: vb.net

I want to save my connection string in XML file.How to do that?How to encrypt and decrypt that file using VB.Net

Comment: what, just some (xml) file on your hard disk? Are you asking for an encryption tool, or do you have some actual programming question?

Comment: I think now you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to encrypt the connectionstrings config section in your applications configuration file, if that's correct then take a look at this:

[How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [Encrypt/Decrypt Files in VB.NET
  (Using Rijndael)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/EncryptFile.aspx)
- [File Encryption in Microsoft
  .NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/ndjodievic/encryp04112005053258AM/encryp.aspx)
- [Google : vb.net encrypt file](http://www.google.co.za/search?hl=en&q=vb.net+encrypt+file&meta=&aq=2&oq=vb.net+encrypt)